# Google Cloud SQL + Hikari CP + Communications link failure

Tags: google-cloud-sql, hikaricp

I'm experiencing intermittent connectivity errors from a Spring Boot application communicating with a D1 Google CloudSQL Server with the configuration settings described here [HikariCP MySQL settings](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration.)

I was wondering if anyone has encountered this before.

I've read the FAQ posted here [Hikari FAQ](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/FAQ) and I'm wondering if my default idleTimeout and maxLifeTime (30 mins) settings might be at fault; wait_timeout and interactive_timeout on the server are both set to default 28800s (8 hours).

The FAQ says that these two settings should be about a minute less that the server settings, but if I'm losing connections after 30 minutes I can't quite see how upping the maxLifeTime to 7hrs 59mins is going to improve the situation.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Redacted stack trace(s):

Get these from time to time

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Timeout after 30018ms of waiting for a connection.
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Timeout after 30023ms of waiting for a connection.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
 ....
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Timeout after 30023ms of waiting for a connection.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:208)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:108)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 59 common frames omitted

    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:630)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:787)
```

Hibernate search:

```
2015-02-17 10:34:17.090  INFO 1 --- [ entityloader-2] o.h.s.i.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor    : HSEARCH000030: 31050 documents indexed in 1147865 ms
2015-02-17 10:34:17.090  INFO 1 --- [ entityloader-2] o.h.s.i.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor    : HSEARCH000031: Indexing speed: 27.050219 documents/second; progress: 99.89%
2015-02-17 10:41:59.917  WARN 1 --- [ntifierloader-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionProxy  : Connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@372f2018 (HikariPool-0) marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0).

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,611,087 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 927,899 milliseconds ago.
```

The indexing isn't particularly quick at the moment I think because I'm not using projections. The process takes about 30 minutes to execute.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What is the specific exception (message) you are getting?  The maxLifeTime should be *at least* 1 minute less than the server-side timeouts.  Another question is, are you getting these errors *in the middle* of executing (multiple) statements on a Connection, or on the *first* statement executed on a Connection from the pool?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I've posted some redacted stack traces that might go someway to answering your questions. I get intermittent connection time outs and at the end of a Hibernate search index I get link failures.

Comment: I've also noticed, on a possibly related note, that when I connect to the instance using MySQL Workbench the connection gets dropped within a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a couple of things here.  First, the network infrastructure (firewalls, load-balancers, etc.) between the application tier and the database tier can impose their own connection timeouts, regardless of MySql settings.

The indexing failure indicates that the connection was out of the pool for ~27 minutes with no SQL activity when that failure occurred.

Second, specifically regarding the "Could not get JDBC Connection" error, you may be running into [Cloud SQL connection limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080166/intermittent-communications-link-failure-with-cloud-sql?rq=1).

I recommend three things.  One, make sure you are on the latest HikariCP (2.3.2) and latest MySql Connector/J driver (5.1.34).  Two, enable DEBUG-level logging for the com.zaxxer.hikari package.  HikariCP debug logging is not "chatty", but will log pool statistics every 30 seconds (and sometimes more detail in failure conditions).  Lastly, try setting the `maxPoolSize` to something smaller (unless already at the default), and setting `maxLifeTime` to 15 or 20 minutes (1200000ms).

If the error occurs again, post updated logs containing the HikariCP debug logs around the time of failure.  Also, feel free to open a tracking issue over on Github as larger logs etc. are easier there.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. The Stack Overflow post your linked suggests a maxPoolSize of about 30. Is that correct?

Comment: That seem right.  Note however, that when HikariCP closes connections, it does so asynchronously.  Usually within several milliseconds.  But it can mean a transient number of one or several live connections above maxPoolSize ... so I would set maxPoolSize to several slots less than the database configured maximum (in this case, maybe 28).

Comment: I've tried 2 of the 3 suggestions. I'll have to investigate how to configure package level log4j with Spring Boot. On a couple of dry runs the indexing process now manages about ~300 documents per second as opposed to ~30 (the performance has however been variable).

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer on the grounds that it appears to have alleviated some to the problems I've been experiencing. The are still problems after mass indexing that I'm going to open a tracking issue for.